# Install redmine 3.0.1 with postgreSql and apache

Tags: postgresql, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine on my server.

The scenario :
  When i go on my server URL -> http:\domain-server.local :
        I got the Apache windows "it works".
  if i try https://domain-server.local/redmine : 
     error :

```
Ruby on Rails application could not be started
A source file that the application requires, is missing.
It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly.         Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this   application requires.
Further information about the error may have been written to the   application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.
Error message:
 cannot load such file -- /opt/config/environment
Exception class:
 LoadError
Application root:
 /opt
```

Now i try that : domain-server.local/redmine:
        i got that error :

> Passenger error #2 An error occurred while trying to access '/var/www/redmine/public/redmine': Cannot resolve possible symlink '/var/www/redmine/public/redmine': No such file or directory (2)

even more strange : when i remove the http:\ from my URL and the /redmine
 i got my redmine working :

```
Environment:
Redmine version                3.0.1.stable
Ruby version                   1.9.3-p194 (2012-04-20) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version                  4.2.0
Environment                    production
Database adapter               PostgreSQL
SCM:
 Subversion                     1.6.17
 Git                            1.7.10.4
 Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
 no plugin installed
```

but i want to access to redmin from http:\domain-server.local/redmine

Here is my apache2.conf file :

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/


RailsBaseURI /redmine
PassengerUserSwitching on
PassengerUser www-data
PassengerGroup www-data

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain-server.local


  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public 

RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /redmine  
  <Directory /var/www/redmine>

     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all

     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews

     # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
     #Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

What's wrong with my install ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I removed the apache2.conf file's content.

I also had 2 different Phusion_Passenger version, so i deleted the oldest and used Phusion_Passenger 5.0.5.

I changed my symlink /var/www/redmine -> /opt/redmine-3.0.1 to /opt/redmine-3.0.1/public

i created the files passenger.load and passenger.conf in /etc/apache2/mods-available/ with the passenger-install-apache2-module instructions .

Then restart apache and it's done !